# react-native-safe-area-context throw `Unresolved reference:` error

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v6

While trying to upgrade `react-native-navigation` I got the following error, after upgrading react-native-safe-area-context

```sh
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
e: /home/me/myProject/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android/src/main/java/com/th3rdwave/safeareacontext/SafeAreaUtils.kt: (12, 34): Unresolved reference: R
e: /home/me/myProject/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android/src/main/java/com/th3rdwave/safeareacontext/SafeAreaUtils.kt: (15, 34): Unresolved reference: getInsets
e: /home/me/myProject/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android/src/main/java/com/th3rdwave/safeareacontext/SafeAreaUtils.kt: (16, 24): Unresolved reference: Type
e: /home/me/myProject/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android/src/main/java/com/th3rdwave/safeareacontext/SafeAreaUtils.kt: (17, 28): Unresolved reference: Type
e: /home/me/myProject/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android/src/main/java/com/th3rdwave/safeareacontext/SafeAreaUtils.kt: (18, 28): Unresolved reference: Type
e: /home/me/myProject/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android/src/main/java/com/th3rdwave/safeareacontext/SafeAreaUtils.kt: (55, 50): Unresolved reference: R
e: /home/me/myProject/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android/src/main/java/com/th3rdwave/safeareacontext/SafeAreaView.kt: (8, 37): Unresolved reference: FabricViewStateManager
e: /home/me/myProject/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android/src/main/java/com/th3rdwave/safeareacontext/SafeAreaView.kt: (9, 37): Unresolved reference: FabricViewStateManager
e: /home/me/myProject/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android/src/main/java/com/th3rdwave/safeareacontext/SafeAreaView.kt: (19, 66): Unresolved reference: HasFabricViewStateManager
e: /home/me/myProject/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android/src/main/java/com/th3rdwave/safeareacontext/SafeAreaView.kt: (24, 41): Unresolved reference: FabricViewStateManager
e: /home/me/myProject/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android/src/main/java/com/th3rdwave/safeareacontext/SafeAreaView.kt: (26, 3): 'getFabricViewStateManager' overrides nothing
e: /home/me/myProject/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android/src/main/java/com/th3rdwave/safeareacontext/SafeAreaView.kt: (26, 45): Unresolved reference: FabricViewStateManager
e: /home/me/myProject/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android/src/main/java/com/th3rdwave/safeareacontext/SafeAreaViewManager.kt: (71, 10): Unresolved reference: fabricViewStateManager

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

My Build-Script:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

## Short Solution:

If you use ReactNative <= 0.63, install `react-native-safe-area-context` in V3 (e.g 3.4.1), as it's not compatible with v4 of `safe-area-context`

---

### Long Painfull journey, that also fix some other of my errors on the way:

This helps me to solve it:

First, set your buildscript-version:

- minSdkVersion = 24 (That is Android 7 [nougat])
- targetSdkVersion =
- compileSdkVersion = 31   (set latest possible here)

Explaination what those Versions do:
| A header | Another header |
| -------- | -------------- |
| minSdkVersion    | set lowest Android-Version you want to support with your app. But keep in mind, that *your app’s minSdkVersion must be at least as high as your dependencie-requirements*
 The Google Play Store also use this to determine which of a user’s devices an app can be installed on |
| targetSdkVersion   | This is the main way Android provides forward compatibility by not applying behavior changes unless the targetSdkVersion is updated           |
| compileSdkVersion| is the Version your app will be compiled with. Changing this Value *does not* change runtime behavior, your compileSdkVersion is not included in your APK |

If you want to read more about this, see [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html?utm_campaign=adp_series_sdkversion_010616&utm_source=medium&utm_medium=blog#ApiLevels)

NOTE: If you increase the compileSdkVersion, make sure, you've also installed the new SDK at your PC.
In my case I missed that and got a non helping error like:

```
* Where:
Build file '/home/me/myProject/android/app/build.gradle' line: 130

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> No signature of method: build_bzoaxr1mlfb80yiyz2yt0w97u.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_bzoaxr1mlfb80yiyz2yt0w97u$_run_closure1) values: [build_bzoaxr1mlfb80yiyz2yt0w97u$_run_closure1@1068678f]
```

E.g. in Android-Studio it looks like this: [image]

Then have a look to upgrade gradle-plugin.

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-gradle

After upgrading Gradle, I got this error:

```
10:01   Gradle sync failed: Could not get unknown property 'compile' for configuration container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationContainer. (3 s 273 ms)
```

So I've changed `from configurations.compile` to `implementation` in `android/app/build.gradle`:

```java
// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.implementation
    into 'libs'
}
```

Then the gradle-sync succeed without error.

As I did this in `android studio` I've cleared the project buy `run > clean project`, but you also can go to `/android` and run `./gradlew clean`

But as I've tried to start the Application, I got an issue. After some search on stackoverflow, the cause seems to be, that RN still not compatible with Gradle7.
So back to 6.9:

```sh
cd /android &&  ./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 6.9
```

I've also had to change build:gradle-tools to 4.2.2

```
dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2')
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! All i did was downgrade from version 4.1.2 to 3.4.1 of react-native-safe-area-context and all the nasty gradle errors and failed builds went away!!

Comment: Downgrading worked. I love you.